# How to periodically update the location to Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a realtime public transport tracking system using Android Studio and Firebase. I have created a toggle button which the user toggle on, the location will start tracking. 
The problem I have faced is the location data only send one time to the database. But for the apps, the location is tracking normally.
What I need is every time the location update have to update into the database. Is that mistake or error in my code?

This is the location callback function:

```
        //Location Callback
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

                if(locationResult == null) {
                  return;
                }
                Location driverLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                Toast.makeText(DriverDetail.this, driverLocation.getLatitude()+", "+driverLocation.getLongitude()
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Location Update: ", "onLocationResult: Location is: "
                        +driverLocation.getLatitude()+", "+driverLocation.getLongitude());
            }
        };
```

This is the code for the Toggle button

```
locate_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View button) {
                if (locate_btn.isChecked()) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    Toast.makeText(DriverDetail.this, "Start tracking location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    final String value_lat = String.valueOf(driverLocation.getLatitude());
                    final String value_lng = String.valueOf(driverLocation.getLongitude());

                    getLocationUpdates();

                    ref.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Latitude").setValue(value_lat);
                    ref.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Longitude").setValue(value_lng);

                }
                else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                    Toast.makeText(DriverDetail.this, "Stop tracking location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

This is the location request that I have set.

```
//Update Location
    private void getLocationUpdates(){

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Check this and trigger firebase update override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {}  https://github.com/GeeksEmpireNet/PinPicsOnMap/blob/master/PinaPiconMapPhone/src/main/java/com/orientation/compasshd/Util/LocationData/Coordinates.kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right now writing the location data to Firebase when the user toggles the button.

What you instead want is to write the location continuously, once the button has been toggled. This means that the writing should happen (or be triggered from) inside `onLocationResult`:

```
locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

        if(locationResult == null) {
          return;
        }
        Location driverLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();

        if (true) { // TODO: check if button is toggled
            final String value_lat = String.valueOf(driverLocation.getLatitude());
            final String value_lng = String.valueOf(driverLocation.getLongitude());

            ref.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Latitude").setValue(value_lat);
            ref.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Longitude").setValue(value_lng);
        }
    }
};
```

In the `if (true)` statement you might want to check if the button is toggled. But since I noticed that you only register for location updates when the user toggles the button, that check might not even be needed.